# Merging one array into another

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

Array 1:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2.3
  2 => 4.5
]
```

Array 2:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "john"
    "age" => 34
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "doe"
    "age" => 12
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "kelvin"
    "age" => 14
  ]
]
```

How do I merge array 1 into array 2 so that I have something like this-

```
array:3 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "name" => "john"
        "age" => 34,
        "score" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "name" => "doe"
        "age" => 12,
        "score" => 2.3
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "name" => "kelvin"
        "age" => 14,
        "score" => 4.5
      ]
    ]
```

Notice that the values of array 1 now have keys called 'score'.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to try to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to walk through the array.

```
<?php

$a = [1,2.3,4.5];

$b = [
    ["name" => "john", "age" => 34],
    ["name" => "doe","age" => 12],
    ["name" => "kelvin", "age" => 14]
];

array_walk($a,function($val,$key) use (&$b){
    $b[$key]['score'] = $val;  
});

print_r($b);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/58rXG

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach loop with [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) `&`:

```
 $ar = [1,2,3.4]; 
 $ar2 = [['name'=>'Joe','age' => 33],['name'=>'Joe2','age' => 33],['name'=>'Joe3','age' => 33]];

 foreach($ar2 as $ind=>&$person){
     $person['score'] = $ar[$ind];
 }

 print_r($ar2);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/uEA9T)**

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe
            [age] => 33
            [score] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe2
            [age] => 33
            [score] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe3
            [age] => 33
            [score] => 3.4
        )

)
```